# Change the root element of a component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

VueJS allows only one root element per component. In most case that's fine to wrap the component inside a `div` tag but it can sometimes cause unexpected behaviors.

For instance, when using Bootstrap, if you put a div between two elements (like `<b-row>` and `<b-col>`), the layout get totally broken.

Many other elements in the framework needs to follow a specific order and that's why having one root element could be problematic.

Is there a way to dynamically set the root element?

To illustrate what i'm saying, take a look at this example:

If a have a component `my-h1` like this:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Hello world</h1>
    </div>
</template>
```

which get called here:

```
<div id="my-app">
    <my-h1 />
</div>
```

The code above will output:

```
<div id="my-app">
    <div>
        <h1>Hello world</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can i get this output:

```
<div id="my-app">
    <p>
        <h1>Hello world</h1>
    </p>
</div>
```

and at another place, this one:

```
<div id="my-app">
    <a>
        <h1>Hello world</h1>
    </a>
</div>
```

(I know these tags doesn't make any sense, it's only for the purpose of this exemple)

---

I hope you see what i mean. Still have one root element, but setting it to be different, with a prop or something else :)

Comment: I think you can achieve this by using slots, or even by passing a prop and checking in the template...

Comment: Can you provide me an example pls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the special [`<component>`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components) component which allows you to choose the component dynamically:

**MyComponent.vue**

```vue
<template>
  <component :is="is" v-bind="props">
    Hello world
  </component>
<template>
```

```es6
export default {
  props: ['is', 'props'],
}
```

Usage is like so:

```vue
<my-component is="div"/>
<my-component is="p"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

With slots you will have to replace the entire component, which I don't think you want.

The other solution will be to pass a **type** property to your component and do a switch (I don't know if it is compliant with vue general philosophy)

But here is an example about what I was thinking:

```
<template>
    <template v-if="type === 'div'">
      <div>
        <h1>Hello world</h1>
      </div>
    </template>

    <template v-else-if="type === 'a'">
      <a>
        <h1>Hello world</h1>
      </a>
    </template>

    <template v-else-if="type === 'p'">
      <p>
        <h1>Hello world</h1>
      </p>
    </template>

    <template v-else>
      <i>
        This is a default
        <b>ITALIC TEXT</b>
      </i>
    </template>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    type: String
  }
};
</script>
```

Then you call your component

```
<component type="div|p|a|whatever"/>
```